# How to use php-amqplib rabbitMQ on web browser

Tags: php, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, php-amqp

I am trying to use php-amqplib for sending and receiving message. It works sending/receiving on terminal. But When go for web browser, unable to receive from queue it continuously waits for message. I used below code for receive.php

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/php-amqplib/amqp.inc');
include_once(__DIR__ . '/config/config.php');
$connection = new AMQPConnection(HOST, PORT, USER, PASS, VHOST);
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare('test22');    
$callback = function($msg){
echo $msg->body;
};    
$channel->basic_consume('test22', 'consumer_tag', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
$channel->wait();
}    
$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

It gets first message from queue if I use below instead of callback function but does not consume from queue

```
$abc=$channel->basic_get("test22", false, 2);    
if(!empty($abc))
{
print_r($abc->body);
}
```

It means messages are available in queue 'test22'.
give me any clue.

Comment: What version of the library are you using? This file `amqp.inc` is not used anymore in modern versions of the library. I suggest you use this one: https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/

Comment: You'd better use php third-party through https://getcomposer.org/.

Comment: Your receive.php / consumer should only be run via terminal as a process. It should then pull messages sent from both the terminal or browser run  scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Change `echo $msg->body;`  to `error_log($msg->body);` (or other loggin system you're using). I think you'll probably will see the messages on the logs. On the web browser the page is already loaded so it won't change even if the script is receiving the message.

Comment: Excellent answer. I had the same problem as @Prak;
your answer solved my problem.